# What operation do these definitions implement? (==, <, >, etc.)

Tags: haskell

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

For example, we can use this data type to represent the first few numerals thusly:

> `Z` stands for `0`, `S Z` stands for `1`, `S (S Z)` stands for `2`, and so on.
>
> 1. Equality (i.e., `x == y`),
> 2. Less than (i.e., `x < y`),
> 3. Less than or equal (i.e., `x ≤ y`),
> 4. Greater than (i.e., `x > y`),
> 5. Greater than or equal (i.e., `x ≥ y`).

1.

```
(?) :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
Z ? Z = True
Z ? (S n) = True
(S n) ? (S m) = n <?> m
x ? z = False
```

2.

```
? :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
(S n) ? Z = True
(S n) ? (S m) = n <?> m
x ? z = False
```

I do not understand what it is referring to with the (S n) nor how we are supposed to differentiate the last X and Z.

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you want to do. Your program has some semantical errors and furthermore what do you mean with `X` and `Z`?

Comment: sorry i need to decide whether these functions represent Equality, Less than, Less than or equal, Greater than or Greater than or equal

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean with *I do not understand what it is referring to with the `(S n)`. If you mean `(S n)` in the head of the function: that is pattern matching. It checks if the value is an `S` constructor, with `n` as argument.

Comment: ok I recognize that. I dont really understand how we are using that constructor to determine the operation.

Comment: well `(S n) ? (S m)` means you have two patterns with constructors `(S x)` the arguments can be different. Apparently for both that means we perform recursion by unpacking both constructors and perform recursion on the arguments. So based on these patterns, you have to look for clues what `?` can be. For instance the first has a line `Z ? Z = True`. So that means that `0 ? 0` is true. There are three relations for which that holds.

Comment: Hint: any `S n` will be always greater or equal to `S Z` which is always greater than `Z` based on natural number ordering.

Comment: Presumably, the lowercase `z`s should be `Z`, although if not they aren't wrong, just misleadingly named patterns.

Comment: Could also just be a catch-all case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your constructors here are

```
-- zero
Z
```

and

```
-- nonzero n
S n
```

Your first example looks at:

```
(?) :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
Z ? Z = True
Z ? (S n) = True
(S n) ? (S m) = n <?> m
x ? z = False
```

So let's go try something. We can start with `(==)` and see if it fails for any of those assertions.

```
Z == Z = True      -- makes sense
Z == (S n) = True  -- FAIL
```

that shouldn't be true, since your zero isn't going to be equal to any non-zero value. In fact, it should be less than any nonzero value! Let's try `(<)` and look at it again

```
Z < Z = True       -- Whoops...
```

Hang on, zeroes aren't less than themselves, but they are less than *or equal to* themselves. Let's test `(<=)`.

```
Z <= Z = True            -- Uh huh
Z <= (S n) = True        -- Yup
(S n) <= (S m) = n <= m  -- S n <= S m when n <= m, makes sense!
x <= z = False           -- Any other construction should be False, e.g.
                         --   (S n) <= Z
```

I'll go ahead and leave the second question to you, now that you hopefully understand what's being asked a bit better!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `S n` as 1 + *n* and `Z` as 0, so for the first operation, you have:

- 0 ? 0 is true
- 0 ? (1 + *n*) for any non-negative *n* is true
- (1 + *n*) ? (1 + *m*) for any non-negative *n* and *m* is the same as *n* ? *m*
- For any other input, it’s false

So you can try each operation (=, <, ≤, >, ≥) in place of ? and see which one produces the same results. E.g.: is 0 ≥ 0? Yes; is 0 ≥ 1 + *n* for non-negative *n*? No; so the function isn’t ≥.

If you’re more familiar with imperative languages, perhaps translating it to another notation would be enlightening. For example, here’s a C version:

```
bool operation(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
  if (a == 0 && b == 0) {
    return true;
  } else if (a == 0 && b != 0) {
    unsigned int n = b - 1;  // Note: unused, as in original code
    return true;
  } else if (a != 0 && b != 0) {
    unsigned int n = a - 1;
    unsigned int m = b - 1;
    return operation(n, m);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Your task is to determine whether this function returns the same results as `==`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=` for all inputs. Note that while I used an integer type (`unsigned int`) here, in reality your `Nat` type is represented in Haskell as a linked list. So I wouldn’t advise doing this “mental translation” too much, except as a learning exercise—in order to faithfully represent what the Haskell code is actually doing, it would take considerably more code.